# adb devices -l not showing Samsung galaxy s3

Tags: java, android, mobile, adt, samsung-mobile

First time to Android programming. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3,
I downloaded and unzipped the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 eclipse and selected my SDK tools and build/platform tools and followed all that is listed on:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

I created a helloworld app, and run "adb devices -l command" but my samsung galaxy s3 was not listed from this command. Here:

```
$ adb devices -l
daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
daemon started successfully * List of devices attached
```

And my device is not listed. It's empty list.
I tried updating my drivers but there is nothing coming out of it. I tried installing samsung Kies 3 but that didn't help as well.

I've to admit, I'm very frustrated with this android thing.
[image]

[image]
My question is: how can I make sure that my samsung galaxy s3 is listed on adb devices list? and so I can run my code on the device directly.

I'm on windows 7, 64 bit. I've java 7 on my machine.

Thank you guys

Comment: try reconnecting the device and seeing if that works. also do you have any kind of tethering on the device?  make sure your screen is unlocked when you connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurray! I actually solved it.

It was just downloading the right driver from samsung website.
1. See the right model of your phone from the settings and search using that model number in samsung site (or any vendor for argument's sake)
2. In windows "manage devices" update your driver.

on command line run:

```
adb devices -l
```

See your device is listed there.

Cheers!